# Миграция с MySQL на MongoDB, не работает выборка по дате

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mongodb, eloquent

Имеется проект с большой базой данных, ранее использовалось в связке с PHP + MySQL с ORM Eloquent, всё работает корректно.

Но проблема следующая, MongoDB с большими данными работает гораздо быстрее, когда нам необходимо получить 3 - 5 миллионов записей из БД для обработки их на PHP сервере, соответственно появился соблазн использовать именно MongoDB, но возникла проблема с выборкой из БД по дате, то есть выборка по дате попросту игнорируется.

Eloquent запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
return Capsule::table('data')
        ->where([
            $whereCode,
            [
                ['time', '>=', $time['start']],
                ['time', '<=', $time['end']]
            ],
            $whereType
        ]);
```

`$whereCode` и `$whereType` - определенные переменные, по которым выводятся записи, `$time['start']` и `$time['end']` - соответственно дата начала и окончания выборки.

С MySQL всё работает корректно, но вот MariaDB игнорирует вывод по дате. В чем может быть проблема?

P.S - так же пробовал и подобный запрос:

```
 return Capsule::table('data')
            ->where([
                $whereCode,
                $whereType
            ])
             ->whereBetween('time', [$time['start'], $time['end']]);
```

C MySQL опять же, всё работает, а вот с MongoDB - нет.

Comment: В MongoDB нужно использовать [MongoDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363724/laravel-5-1-mongodb-jenssegers-laravel-mongodb-querying-dates-not-working-righ) [формат](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php)

Comment: Сколько не гуглил - подобных вещей не находил (с MongoDB в целом плохо знаком), спасибо за подсказку. По возможности попробую через MongoDate.